# changing a certain value in a specific location in a text file under linux, done for multiple files

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have almost 500 text files, each file contains 5 columns of numbers and almost 100 rows, I'd like to change all the 10's to 15's for example but only in the first column. can this be done using sed? or awk? I'd also like to do that for all 500 files at once.

sample input (simplified)

```
10  10  19  
21  15  18 
10  25  10
```

desired output

```
15  10  19
21  15  18
15  25  10
```

Comment: If you haven't already tried anything yourself (you should), at least some sample input and desired output would be useful.

Comment: All files in one folder or spread in sevaral subfolders?

Comment: Markus. In one folder. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace in every line that *starts* with 10 ... the regex character <kbd>^</kbd> matches at the start of a line.

If your text files are all in a subtree of a directory "yourdir" you can find all those files and run sed against them:

`find youdir -name \*.txt -exec sed -i '' -e 's/^10 /15 /' {} +`

or more simply, if all of your text files are in the current directory:

`sed -i '' -e 's/^10 /15 /' *.txt`

These say to substitute a one-zero-space with a one-five-space at the beginning of the line.

The `-i ''` option says to modify the files in-place with no backup.

Comment: will that work only for the first column? keeping in mind that the location of the one-zero-space is not the same for all 500 files? Thanks

Comment: @nytrook - you don't really have "columns" in you sample input, you simply have lines of space-separated numbers. The `sed` substitution I've shown works only when the first number begins as the first character in a line. If you have leading spaces, or something preceding the numbers this won't work, and you should show it in your sample input.

Comment: Perhaps your "sample input (simplified)" is overly simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Given this input file:

```
$ cat file
10 10 19
21 15 18
10 25 10
```

Generically, to change number `old` to number `new` in row `row`, column `col` is:

```
$ awk -v old=10 -v new=37 -v row=1 -v col=1 'NR==row && $col==old{$col=new} 1' file
37 10 19
21 15 18
10 25 10
```

In column `col` of all rows:

```
$ awk -v old=10 -v new=37 -v col=1 '$col==old{$col=new} 1' file
37 10 19
21 15 18
37 25 10
```

In row `row` of all columns:

```
$ awk -v old=10 -v new=37 -v row=1 'NR==row{ for(col=i;col<=NF;col++) $col=($col==old?new:$col)} 1' file
37 37 19
21 15 18
10 25 10
```

You see the pattern...

Comment: Ed Morton: yup. Thanks for your input.